# JMeter - Parameter Name for Binary Image on a Local folder

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

How can I find out the Parameter Name of a Binary image (abc.jpg) saved on my local drive C:\Users\NY\Documents? Everyone says it should be the "name" attribute but that's for the image on a website. When I check the properties of the Binary image I have, the Attributes is listed as 'A'. If I give 'A' as a Parameter Name under Files Upload tab in HTTP Request, I can see that the image is uploaded but it gets corrupted, and I suspect it's because I didn't give the Parameter Name correctly. I cannot record it on JMeter to get the Parameter Name either. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what "everyone says", there are multiple ways of implementing file upload on the server side.

If it's a [HTML Form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) indeed you need to provide the value of its ["name" attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_name.asp),see  for example it can be uploaded with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

In case you don't know what is the server-side implementation you can just record the request using your browser and JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just **make sure to copy the file to JMeter's "bin" folder**, in this case JMeter will be able to properly capture the request and generate the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)